# How to overcome kinect sdk 2 installation failure on windows 10

Tags: windows, sdk, windows-installer, kinect, kinect-sdk

A Windows 10 laptop fails during Kinect SDK v2 installation. The SDK was previously working on this machine when the OS was at either Windows version 8 or 8.1.  I have since upgraded to Windows 10 and am unable to reinstall the Kinect SDK 2 (which had been uninstalled in the interim).

There is similar question about Windows 8.1 laptop, but no real answer to that post except the OP himself, who says he repeatedly retried 25 times and finally magically succeeded. I can't tell if it's exactly the same issue.

The error message at the end of the install process simply pointed me at the log file which I can't turn into a fix.  Is there any systematic way to overcome an install error for Kinect SDK 2 on Windows 10 when a previous install worked fine on the very same machine with an earlier version of the OS?

The log file:

```
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:44]i001: Burn v3.7.1224.0, Windows v6.2 (Build 9200: Service Pack 0), path: E:\Brekel Installers\BrekelPro PointCloud v2\KinectSDK-v2.0_1409-Setup.exe, cmdline: ''
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:44]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\ROBBAE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Kinect_for_Windows_SDK_v2.0_1409_20160313193444.log'
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:44]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'E:\Brekel Installers\Brekel Pro PointCloud v2\KinectSDK-v2.0_1409-Setup.exe'
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:44]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Kinect for Windows SDK v2.0_1409'
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:44]i000: Loading managed bootstrapper application.
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:44]i000: Creating BA thread to run asynchronously.
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:44]i100: Detect begin, 5 packages
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:44]i000: Setting string variable 'VCRTx64Installed' to value '1'
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:44]i000: Setting string variable 'VCRTx86Installed' to value '1'
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:44]i052: Condition 'VCRTx86Installed' evaluates to true.
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:44]i052: Condition 'VCRTx64Installed' evaluates to true.
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:44]i101: Detected package: VCRTx86, state: Present, cached: None
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:44]i101: Detected package: VCRTx64, state: Present, cached: None
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:44]i101: Detected package: x64Runtime, state: Absent, cached: None
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:44]i101: Detected package: x64SDK, state: Absent, cached: None
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:44]i101: Detected package: x64Drivers, state: Absent, cached: None
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:44]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:48]i200: Plan begin, 5 packages, action: Install
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:48]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: VCRTx86
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:48]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:48]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: VCRTx64
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:48]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:48]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_x64Runtime' to value 'C:\Users\ROBBAE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Kinect_for_Windows_SDK_v2.0_1409_20160313193444_0_x64Runtime_rollback.log'
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:48]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_x64Runtime' to value 'C:\Users\ROBBAE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Kinect_for_Windows_SDK_v2.0_1409_20160313193444_0_x64Runtime.log'
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:48]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:48]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_x64SDK' to value 'C:\Users\ROBBAE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Kinect_for_Windows_SDK_v2.0_1409_20160313193444_1_x64SDK_rollback.log'
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:48]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_x64SDK' to value 'C:\Users\ROBBAE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Kinect_for_Windows_SDK_v2.0_1409_20160313193444_1_x64SDK.log'
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:48]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:48]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_x64Drivers' to value 'C:\Users\ROBBAE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Kinect_for_Windows_SDK_v2.0_1409_20160313193444_2_x64Drivers_rollback.log'
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:48]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_x64Drivers' to value 'C:\Users\ROBBAE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Kinect_for_Windows_SDK_v2.0_1409_20160313193444_2_x64Drivers.log'
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:48]i201: Planned package: VCRTx86, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:48]i201: Planned package: VCRTx64, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:48]i201: Planned package: x64Runtime, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: Register
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:48]i201: Planned package: x64SDK, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: Register
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:34:48]i201: Planned package: x64Drivers, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: Register
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:35:03]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:35:03]i300: Apply begin
 [28F4:28EC][2016-03-13T19:35:58]i360: Creating a system restore point.
 [28F4:28EC][2016-03-13T19:35:58]i361: Created a system restore point.
 [28F4:28EC][2016-03-13T19:35:58]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\ROBBAE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{2f7f3dc4-de9a-4605-821f-b686f26392d8}\.be\KinectSDK-v2.0_1409-Setup.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{2f7f3dc4-de9a-4605-821f-b686f26392d8}\KinectSDK-v2.0_1409-Setup.exe'
 [28F4:28EC][2016-03-13T19:35:58]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {2f7f3dc4-de9a-4605-821f-b686f26392d8}, version: 2.0.1410.19000
 [28F4:10D8][2016-03-13T19:35:59]i305: Verified acquired payload: x64Runtime at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\x64Runtime, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{5045CFA2-C173-4678-82AD-02BFD77ED26A}v2.0.1410.18000\KinectRuntime-x64.msi.
 [28F4:10D8][2016-03-13T19:36:05]e000: Error 0x80070057: Failed to move verified file to complete payload path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{5045CFA2-C173-4678-82AD-02BFD77ED26A}v2.0.1410.18000\KinectRuntime-x64.msi
 [28F4:10D8][2016-03-13T19:36:05]e000: Error 0x80070057: Failed to cache payload: x64Runtime
 [202C:2178][2016-03-13T19:36:05]e314: Failed to cache payload: x64Runtime from working path: C:\Users\ROBBAE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{2f7f3dc4-de9a-4605-821f-b686f26392d8}\x64Runtime, error: 0x80070057.
 [202C:2178][2016-03-13T19:36:05]e349: Application requested retry of payload: x64Runtime, encountered error: 0x80070057. Retrying...
 [28F4:10D8][2016-03-13T19:36:05]i305: Verified acquired payload: x64Runtime at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\x64Runtime, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{5045CFA2-C173-4678-82AD-02BFD77ED26A}v2.0.1410.18000\KinectRuntime-x64.msi.
 [28F4:10D8][2016-03-13T19:36:12]e000: Error 0x80070057: Failed to move verified file to complete payload path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{5045CFA2-C173-4678-82AD-02BFD77ED26A}v2.0.1410.18000\KinectRuntime-x64.msi
 [28F4:10D8][2016-03-13T19:36:12]e000: Error 0x80070057: Failed to cache payload: x64Runtime
 [202C:2178][2016-03-13T19:36:12]e314: Failed to cache payload: x64Runtime from working path: C:\Users\ROBBAE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{2f7f3dc4-de9a-4605-821f-b686f26392d8}\x64Runtime, error: 0x80070057.
 [202C:2178][2016-03-13T19:36:12]e349: Application requested retry of payload: x64Runtime, encountered error: 0x80070057. Retrying...
 [28F4:10D8][2016-03-13T19:36:12]i305: Verified acquired payload: x64Runtime at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\x64Runtime, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{5045CFA2-C173-4678-82AD-02BFD77ED26A}v2.0.1410.18000\KinectRuntime-x64.msi.
 [28F4:10D8][2016-03-13T19:36:18]e000: Error 0x80070057: Failed to move verified file to complete payload path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{5045CFA2-C173-4678-82AD-02BFD77ED26A}v2.0.1410.18000\KinectRuntime-x64.msi
 [28F4:10D8][2016-03-13T19:36:18]e000: Error 0x80070057: Failed to cache payload: x64Runtime
 [202C:2178][2016-03-13T19:36:18]e314: Failed to cache payload: x64Runtime from working path: C:\Users\ROBBAE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{2f7f3dc4-de9a-4605-821f-b686f26392d8}\x64Runtime, error: 0x80070057.
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:36:18]e000: Error 0x80070057: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
 [28F4:28EC][2016-03-13T19:36:18]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {2f7f3dc4-de9a-4605-821f-b686f26392d8}
 [28F4:28EC][2016-03-13T19:36:18]i352: Removing cached bundle: {2f7f3dc4-de9a-4605-821f-b686f26392d8}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{2f7f3dc4-de9a-4605-821f-b686f26392d8}\
 [202C:07C4][2016-03-13T19:36:21]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070057, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Answer (score 2):

What finally worked for me was to delete the program cache folder ['C:\ProgramData\Package Cache'].  Note that C:/ProgramData is  a hidden folder.

I tried the suggestion of running **sfc /scannow** from the administrative command console (cmd), and it did not work for me.

Comment: Hi friend! maintain one account ... it will help you to organize your question, answers etc. Thanks.

Comment: Yes sorry. It was a Chrome setting mistake (work/personal) on my initial post.  Sometimes "automagic authentication" gets the best of us.

Comment: Hi. I renamed "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache" folder (just to avoid deleting it). Then, I tried to install the SDK from my downloads folder again, and got the same error. But the system created a new folder "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache", and within it, there was another folder (named with a huge number code), where I could find a new copy of the SDK executable. Finally, I run this file (direct from "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{bignumberhere}" and the install was sucessfull. Thanx @RobBaer

Answer (score 0):

The problem may can be with the graphic card. Make sure you have enabled the graphic card as the main video output. I had the same problem and when I have tried with the graphic, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your PC may be missing some .dll without explicitely telling which ones.

I reinstalled  MSVCR110.dll with
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679
and it solved the issue.